# Automatically grab website caption on Facebook feed dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

In Facebook official documentation, they supply this code in order to put a feed dialog in an application:

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'feed',
   link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
   picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
   name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
   caption: 'Reference Documentation',
   description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with people.'
}, function(response){});
```

Is it possibile to automatically grab picture, name and caption from the link supplied by the user, as feed posts normally behave on Facebook?

Comment: No. It's not possible.!

Comment: These parameters enable you to _overwrite_ the info that Facebook would normally grab from the given link – if you _don’t_ want to overwrite those values, then just leave those parameters out …

Comment: Hi CBroe, I tried to leave those parameters blank, but when I try to post my feed I cannot see the caption...